# Installing OpenFOAM through Docker

Tags: terminal, docker, installation, openfoam

I'm having a bad time trying to install OpenFOAM using Docker(on a MacOSX El Capitan). I've been following the [official tutorial](http://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary.php).

When I try to execute the first script (installOpenFOAM+), through the command line:

```
docker-machine ssh default $HOME/installOpenFOAM+ $HOME
```

I get the following result on the terminal screen:

> machine does not exist

I've been looking for a solution online over and over but it seems nobody has had an issue like this. Has someone here faced the same problem?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on http://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary.php to install OpenFOAM via Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the install script executable before the first script, it seems to work for some people. That is, use

```
chmod +x installOpenFOAM+
```

Comment: You are correct! I forgot to update here with the answer but just after posting I've received a feedback from the openCFD team suggesting to do the same thing. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

I also had tough time installing Openfoam using docker.

After you install docker, you need to create a virtual machine (named default).
Once it is done, change the permission of install script. Then try to install it.

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
chmod a+x installMacOpenFOAM+
docker-machine ssh default $HOME/installMacOpenFOAM+ $HOME
```

I am not able to stat the application.